# Display list of all neighbourhoods in a city

Tags: api, maps, geo-location, google-maps, address-book

I am developing a real estate application using react-native and node express,
and I'm really close to the end, I have used google maps API to display the property on a map and for the address auto complete.

now the only thing I'm missing is when a user want to filter the properties he can select a city (using google maps autocomplete api) and then I want to let him choose a neighbourhood inside the city but as far as I could found google maps don't provide that service (which is really weird for me because you can for example, see a neighbourhood boundaries in google map) so I have 2 questions:

1) Do you have any recommendation for an API who knows to return a list of all neighbourhood within a city ? 
2) How could I make sure if my property (full address) is within that neighbourhood area?

That things appear in million real estates website I'm surprised it is so hard to find

Comment: You might ask for a dataset on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ and use that ....

Comment: Sometimes a city might have formal "neighborhood" definitions for its own planning; but more often than not neighborhoods are much more organic - the people living in/near them give them names to explain the world around them.

Comment: Geonames.org is probably worth a look, although I don't know how complete the data at the neighborhood level is, and whether it has decent polygons for them (rather than centroid points)